# How can I plot pixels onto the screen without WinForms using F#/C#?

Tags: c#, dll, f#, draw, pixel

I want to know how to get and set pixel that are currently shown on the screen, I'm sure this must be possible I just don't know how. Would I need to use a DLL? I don't have any code to show at this point but I just needed to be pointed in the right direction, I can for the most part port from C# to F# if you can only answer in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this question:
[How to read screen pixels for an application that is not in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548901/how-to-read-screen-pixels-for-an-application-that-is-not-in-the-foreground)

```
using (Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
{
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture))
  {
     g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, bmpScreenCapture.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
  }
  Color c = bmpScreenCapture.GetPixel(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is very useful, but how do I set the pixels anywhere to the screen?

Comment: That, I don't know. I suspect that may not be allowed because you need to draw on a window owned by your program. You could draw on a transparent window hovering on top of the others, but it would probably block access to the other windows.